# Finding the value of $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, orthogonality

Find the value of $k$ so that the lines defined by the equations
$$\frac{x-3}{3k+1}=\frac{y+6}{2}   =   \frac{z+3}{2k}$$ and $$\frac{x+7}{3}=\frac{y+8}{-2k}=\frac{z+9}{-3}$$ are perpendicular.

Comment: $\frac{x-3}{3k+1} = \frac{y+6}{2}  = \frac{z+3}{2k} $ and $\frac{x+7}{3} = \frac{y+8}{-2k} = \frac{z+9}{-3} $ are perpendicular? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes! i was not sure how to format it! thank you!

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant tags. At the moment, this has nothing to do with calculus. Also, you're expected to include your thoughts and work in progress in ever post. It would also benefit you if you formatted your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It does... It is a question from my Calculus course on the Planes and Lines  Unit review. And I truly have no idea where to start with this question

Comment: So you haven't tried anything? Perhaps this isn't the right question to ask then. What about the question confuses you?

Comment: I was going to say that although the problem might come from a calculus book, or is an intermediate step to solve a calculus problem, the current posted problem has nothing to do with calculus. The title of the section even says "Planes and Lines unit review"..........................

Comment: I don't understand where to find the value of k and how to make the lines perpendicular. I know that for the lines to be perpendicular they have to have the same slope but how do I determine that?

Comment: perpendicular lines **do not** have the same slope.

Comment: Information like that would be helpful in your posts. For future reference, you might want to look at these three pages: [Page 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Page 2](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). [Page 3](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Ok! Thank you probablyme!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have

$$v_1(3k+1,2,2k), v_2(3,-2k,-3)$$

and in order to be perpendicular,

$$v_1 * v_2 = 0$$

then multiply and set equal to $0$,

$$3(3k+1)+2*(-2k)-3*2k = 0$$

$$k=3$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $\vec{w}=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$, are perpendicular if
$$\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=0\qquad\text{i.e.}\qquad v_1w_1+v_2w_2+v_3w_3=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The two lines have [direction vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_vector) respectively $(3k+1,2,2k)$ and $(3,-2k,-3)$.
The [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of these vectors is

$$9k+3-4k-6k=3-k$$

Equate this to zero to find when the lines are perpendicular.

---

Just a precision: an equation $\frac{x-a}{u}=\frac{y-b}{v}=\frac{z-c}{w}$ is equivalent to $x=a+ut,y=b+vt,z=c+wt$, with parameter $t$. That is, a line with direction vector $(u,v,w)$, passing through the point $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: Am I doing this right? Because my answer comes to k=0.

Comment: @Karen Update your answer to show what you have done, so that somebody can show you where it may be wrong.

Comment: I believed that I should substitute 0 for k. So 9(0)+3−4(0)−6(0)=3−(0) which equal 3-3=0. I think solved it wrong.

Comment: @Karen Oh, I see. The scalar product has value $9k+3-4k-6k$. This expression simplifies to $3-k$. This was not an equation $9k+3-4k-6k=3-k$, I just wanted to show that the left-hand side simplifies to the right-hand side. And you equate one of them to zero. That is, $3-k=0$. Anyway, even if you see this as an equation, you will fail, because it will be equivalent to $0=0$, and will not give you a value for $k$.